How do I search a column and return the entire row?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $text = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['errortext']));
}

 $sqlError = "SELECT ERRORSTRING FROM Errors";
 $stmtError = $db->query($sqlError);
   while ($rows = $stmtError->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
     foreach($rows as $row => $val) {
       if($text != null){
         if(str_contains($val, $text)){
           echo $val . '<br>';
         }
       }
     }
   }

I am creating an error log that a user can search through. The database has 14 fields, 3 are searchable. The example above is the ERRORSTRING field.
A user searches a term. I want it to echo the entire row that term was found in. I am able to get the error code and column title but can't get it to do what I want.

I'm not familiar with sqlite syntax specifically, but couldn't you do something like select * from errors WHERE ERRORSTRING = 'userInputHere'?

As an addition to @mykaf very correct suggestion, make sure you that you don't just concatenate in your user's input into the WHERE clause, bind the value, otherwise you will be open for a sql injection attack. As an added bonus, the example in that link is very similar to your usecase, so you can copy/paste your way through this (for the most part).

htmlspecialchars() should be used to escape text that's being output on a web page. It shouldn't be used on input data.

Use LIKE rather than = to search for the string anywhere in the column.

Instead of searching in the logic while not search from the database so you get all corresponding data based on the search
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $text = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['errortext']));
}

$val = $errorString;
$sqlError = "SELECT * FROM Errors where column like '%$errorString%' ";
$stmtError = $db->query($sqlError);
while ($rows = $stmtError->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
  foreach ($rows as $row => $val) {
        echo $val . '<br>';
  }
}


FYI: Is htmlspecialchars enough to prevent an SQL injection
